# jQuery UI Autocomplete on keyup?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm working with the jQuery UI library's [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) functionality. I have two form fields on a webpage - one is internal search, and one searches content my company manages on a third party site via a REST API.

This works as it should - if I have the two form fields sitting next to each other, I can type into either and get the autocomplete results for that datasource below.

What I've been asked to do, though, is combine the two fields into one "master" search field and hide the two individual fields. It would search *both* data sources for the user's input, and display the results in separate ui-autocomplete boxes below the field.

My idea is that if I could just change the trigger method for autocomplete from "focus" to "keyup" it would work very nicely, or if I could "fake" the focus trigger without sending the cursor to the hidden field.

Any ideas on this?

**Update:**

Here's the code I've been trying, and it doesn't work. This is what lead me to think I was dependent on the focus event.

```
$(function(){
// run autocomplete on form fields
searchAutocomplete('/support/results_json/','#keywords');
searchAutocomplete('/support/zdresults_json/','#zd_search');
//$('#ee_searchform').hide(); // will need this later
//$('#zd_searchform').hide(); // will need this later
$('<form id="support_search" class="group" method=""><fieldset><legend>Search Support</legend><ol><li><label for="support_keywords">Keywords</label><input type="search" value="" name="support_keywords" id="support_keywords" /></li><li class="submit"><input type="submit" name="support_submit" id="support_submit" value="Search" /></li></ol></form>').insertAfter('#zd_searchform');

$('#support_keywords').keyup(function() {
  var value = $('#support_keywords').val();
    $('#keywords').val(value);
    $('#keywords').keyup();
}); 
});
```

So you can see, I take the two form fields that the HTML contains, and make sure they call the working autocomplete function. Then I use jQuery to add another form to the DOM, and when it gets a keyup it adds its contents to one of the other fields, and gives that field a keyup. This doesn't call the autocomplete, though.

Many thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by the "focus" trigger? Suggestions are already displayed on `keyup`

Answer (score 0):

My first thought here is to hide the original fields (on focus if you want) and inject a new one prior to or in combination with the individual focus events then suggest you manage the autocomplete source:

```
source: function(request, response)
    {
        // do both your ajax calls here and combine your results prior to providing to your field
    }
```

THEN, you can handle the results using some combination of:

```
source: function(request, response)
            {response(rows);},//where rows is an array of results
search:function(event, ui){},
focus:function(event, ui){},
open:function(event, ui){},
```

and finally

```
select: function(event, ui)
            {}//handle what to do with the selection of/from the results list
```

This would help avoid any fancy/complicated management of entry state and you can then manage the results presentation.

EDIT: Example of multiple ajax concats (very simple and no sorting etc)

See this fiddle page for some stuff (does not run as-is due to the json ajax not being present but you can work with it I hope)
http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/Z6rVE/

As written, it assumes a json with MyCode, Description, and SourceTable

```
[{"MyCode":"code","Description":"my desc","SourceTable":"mysource"},{"MyCode":"code","Description":"my desc","SourceTable":"mysource"}]
```

you just need each source to say the SourceTable (or add new stuff you might need)

Comment: Many thanks. I think you're pointing me in the perfect direction. I can add both ajax calls inside source - `source: function(request, response) { $.ajax({url, datatype, data, success $.ajax({url, datatype, data, success }` but I'm not sure how to separate the results? I thought maybe I could make response an array, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You can return ANYTHING you want in the ajax result, the trick is then (in this case) to return EXTRA stuff to identify which ajax the result chosen is from.  I will post an example of parsing results to enable such a thing.

Comment: Thanks, I'd love to see that.

Comment: Note that my example adds the selection as data to the entry field if you wish to use that part to capture the results of a selection.

Comment: I finally figured out why I couldn't get this to work (off and on time for this, these days)! The final result variables in your example - rowsFirst and rowsSecond - don't ever get assigned because jQuery's ajax function apparently cannot return a value for use outside it.

Comment: this also could be becasue my syntax `rowsFirst.concat(rowsSecond);` was wrong in the fiddle page :{  I have `rowsFirst.cotat`